# Should I dispute fraudulent hard inquiries on my credit report?

Tags: credit-report, identity-theft

A store credit card was opened fraudulently in my name, and I am going through the process of disputing and having it removed from credit reports.

Within a few days of that account being opened, several hard inquiries for other store cards were made and show up on my credit report, but were presumably denied.

Since I was preparing to shop for auto loans, is it worthwhile to also dispute the hard inquiries? What documentation will be expected? I don't want to spend more time than necessary cleaning things up if there is little benefit. I normally keep my credit files frozen because of past identity theft.

Answer (score 2):

What was your score prior to the hard inquiries?  What is it after?  I suspect that there was not a huge change.  In the name of convenience why bother?  See this [Q & A](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/how-much-does-credit-score-matter) for more info.

Comment: Overall score dropped 150 points but I can't tell what part of that is due to the hard inquiries alone because of the account that was successfully opened and is currently flagged delinquent. That is why I ask about impact of lots of hard inquiries in general.

Comment: I don't think you need documentation to dispute something on your credit report. As far as I understand, it is up to the company that reported it, to verify or at least assert that it is correct. That said, inquiries probably don't have that much of an effect on your score... the delinquent, fraudulent account sounds much more serious and you should be doing your best to solve this problem with the utmost alacrity!